# The right ruby driver for ScyllaDB

Tags: ruby, scylla, datastax-ruby-driver

We decided to work with ScyllaDB for some heavy-insert components in our Ruby on Rails project. However, the [ruby driver](https://github.com/datastax/ruby-driver) is said to be in maintenance mode and also we heard of its performance issues a couple of years ago.

My question is if someone really works on production with ScyllaDB with ruby? What driver do you use? How does it perform? Are there any pitfalls that we should be aware of?
Btw, I know about DynamoDB alternator, but we really prefer to use CQL as opposed to weird DynamoDB json query syntax and need additional Scylla features, like "group by", multi-column partition keys and more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We currently use a combination of Cequel and the Ruby driver you linked (which Cequel uses under the hood). In our first ScyllaDB/Cassandra project, we assumed that the flexible schemas were more flexible than they actually are (e.g., you can't change keys around without considerations), so Cequel sounded like a good fit. In our second project, which we chose keys and the like very deliberately, we just use the underlying driver semi-directly (we use `Cequel::Metal`). We handle migrations with a Rake task because migrations don't really work the same as with PostgreSQL (up/down don't make sense in the traditional sense - you don't lose the new columns if you migrate down, you just lose them from *new* records).

The default answer in the Cassandra community appears to be "run JRuby, use the JDBC driver". Don't do that. JRuby can be great, for the right people, but it's not totally MRI compatible, and it doesn't perform the same. They'll next suggest ODBC. `ruby-odbc` should be considered a last resort compatibility library. It has a lot of unimplemented ODBC features. It can leak ODBC state and lock up that thread, or crash the process(!) if the driver doesn't guard against poor thread safety. It will perform exceptionally poorly in Rails. Don't go that route either.

These two suggestions are about all you get, at least from when I looked around. It would appear that within the Cassandra community, a lot of people are still applying 10 years ago Ruby impressions to modern Ruby. By that, I mean they assume that JRuby is faster than MRI due to the JVM, because Twitter dropped Rails and switched to the JVM. This isn't really the case anymore (and hasn't been in some time). There are some situations where JRuby excels, but plenty where MRI beats it. The folks recommending JDBC probably have good intentions, but it feels a lot like "your language sucks, use ours". This attitude seems to cause them to spend time doing e.g., Python or Go drivers, but not Ruby drivers.

If ScyllaDB were paying me to work on a driver, I would [take their C/C++ driver](https://github.com/scylladb/cpp-driver) and use FFI to wrap it and expose a decent API. I would probably not write an ActiveRecord driver because I don't use ScyllaDB/Cassandra for our primary data objects, and non-key-based queries (the main reason you'd use ActiveRecord) aren't possible without `WITH FILTERING`, which you *probably* do not want to make available to HTTP clients. You can use materialized views and all that, but then the query is slightly different. A library on top of this could map these concepts to ActiveRecord. The hard part with a FFI wrapper will be to thoughtfully design an idiomatic interface; the rest is thankfully pretty easy due to the FFI project's efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If someone was interested in forking the Ruby driver for use with Scylla a few thoughts on how they could proceed.

1. Make it shard-aware. We've seen other recent efforts for a shard aware Python driver (the how-to can be found in these posts: [part 1](https://www.scylladb.com/2020/10/13/making-a-shard-aware-python-driver-for-scylla-part-1/) and [part 2](https://www.scylladb.com/2020/10/15/making-a-shard-aware-python-driver-for-scylla-part-2/)). For instance we already have shard-aware [GoCQL/GoCQLX](https://www.scylladb.com/2018/02/12/gocql-gocqlx-scylla/), [Rust](https://www.scylladb.com/2021/02/17/scylla-developer-hackathon-rust-driver/) and [C/C++](https://github.com/scylladb/cpp-driver) drivers (I'm working on editing the blog for C/C++ now). So that way is well-trod ground.
2. Make the shard-aware driver support CDC streams (see [today's blog post](https://www.scylladb.com/2021/03/09/making-shard-aware-drivers-for-cdc/)). This is a new feature, and you can see from the post that we're in process of getting this feature added to the current drivers. But if you were to do Ruby you should start with this in mind.

If you get no further answers here on users' experiences, please also ask on the ScyllaDB [user Slack](http://slack.scylladb.com/) or [email list](https://groups.google.com/g/scylladb-users).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [Scylla Alternator](https://www.scylladb.com/alternator/) (DynamoDB compatible API) in which case you can use AWS DynamoDB drivers. Performance won't be as good as CQL, but it will still be very fast and you will be able to use libraries like [Dynamoid](https://github.com/Dynamoid/dynamoid).